# File missing in server after an apparently successful upload in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to implement the **ng-file-upload** solution to my app.

So far I managed to upload and get a successfull callback, but when I check the upload folder through the FTP, it's still empty.

Here's my button:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 last" ngf-select="upload($file)">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/add.png" />
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'upload.php',
        data: {
             file: file,
            'targetPath' : '/uploads/'
        }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + ' uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
};
```

My PHP code:

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$meta = $_POST;
$destination = $meta['targetPath'] . $filename;
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , $destination );
```

And the response I get:

```
progress: 47% 13428596_10153653711491485_8982166664082945936_n.jpg
progress: 71% 13428596_10153653711491485_8982166664082945936_n.jpg
progress: 94% 13428596_10153653711491485_8982166664082945936_n.jpg
progress: 100% 13428596_10153653711491485_8982166664082945936_n.jpg

angular.js:11881 XHR finished loading: POST "http://cccctanger.com/miquelimarc/upload.php".    

Success 13428596_10153653711491485_8982166664082945936_n.jpg uploaded.     
Response:  $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$meta = $_POST;
$destination = $meta['targetPath'] . $filename;
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , $destination );
```

It seems everything is fine, but no uploaded file to be found.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where's the server side code?

Comment: @AlonEitan I didn't do any, nor is to be found on the examples I saw! : /

Comment: It doesn't work that way, you can't just directly upload the file to the server for some random directory. You create a script that copy the file to the directory

Comment: @AlonEitan Are you sure? It doesn't mention anything on the [project page](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#server-side)

Comment: Woops! Missed that one!

Comment: @AlonEitan See edit. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You need to pass the file inside ´data{}´

Comment: @AlonEitan I did, still nothing.